# Combine Two Classes in CSS?

Tags: css, class

I have tried to combine to classes in CSS, but I end up failing. I used this code:

`.container{
  .ningbar
}`

What I would like to do is combine the items in the ningbar layer with the items in the container layer. Thanks, Phineas.

Comment: `.container { /*container rules*/ }`, `.ningbar { /*ningbar rules*/ }`, `.container,.ningbar { /*shared rules*/ }`.

Comment: Try to look at less or sass. It would help. In css right way look in answer below

Comment: What does "combine" mean exactly? Do you want to match items with `container` *and* `ningbar`?

Comment: Alvaro, he wants to add attributes from one class to another, as a see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job:

```
.container { /*container rules*/ }

.ningbar { /*ningbar rules*/ }

.container,.ningbar { /*shared rules*/ }
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like them to have all the rules the same.

Comment: @Phineas0510 use the third one that MelanciaUK wrote. If you want it to have all the same rules.

Comment: Your Welcome. Please accept @MelanciaUK answer if this is the solution.

Comment: I put on the answer a way where you can have particular rules for each one, just in case. If they're always following the same rules, the third selector is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`.container, .ningbar { }`

Use the same rules for both.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to combine two classes ? I would make two seperate classes and use them in my controls as below

CSS:

```
.class1{
    /* All styles for class1*/
}

.class2{
    /* All styles for class2*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

This way you can add both classes to your controls/DOM elements keeping them seperate in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use another styles' for another class, there is LESS, if I can say.

In a nutshell, LESS will help you to maintain more easily, and comprehensible your styles' files. You will be able to add variables, to avoid repetitions of same colors' codes, for instance.

You can view more detail on LESS's website : http://lesscss.org/

But, it's probably a complicated way, to simply add properties from another class.

Answer (score 0):

For Combining two class you can us 
`.Class1 .Class2 {
   //All style for combination of these two classes
    }`